# Remove wishlist and compare links next to add to cart button on product listing page

Tags: magento2

I can't seem to locate where the add to wishlist or compare buttons next to the add to cart button on the product listing page are?

Comment: Have you tried the list.phtml template under catalog view?

Comment: There's a similar post that seems to have good answers:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/96934/magento-2-safe-and-easiest-way-to-disable-compare-products-wishlist-module/139720#139720?newreg=fd3743270edd4ac1ae7f041e22c818a1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add xml code to `catalog_product_view.xml` in your

```
<magento-theme>/<magento-catalog> to remove wishlist and compare links
<referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.link" remove="true" /> <!--for My
Compare Link-->

 <referenceBlock name="wish-list-link" remove="true" /> <!--for My
Wishlist Link-->
```