# how to disable Add to compare option in list.phtml file magento 2 custom theme?

Tags: magento2

> E:\xampp\htdocs\mage\app\design\frontend\Hiddentechies\bizkick\Magento_Catalog\templates\product\list.phtml

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>
<?php
/**
 * Product list template
 *
 * @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct
 */
?>
<?php
$_productCollection = $block->getLoadedProductCollection();
$_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
?>
<?php if (!$_productCollection->count()): ?>
    <div class="message info empty"><div><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('We can\'t find products matching the selection.') ?></div></div>
<?php else: ?>
    <?= $block->getToolbarHtml() ?>
    <?= $block->getAdditionalHtml() ?>
    <?php
    if ($block->getMode() == 'grid') {
        $viewMode = 'grid';
        $image = 'category_page_grid';
        $showDescription = false;
        $templateType = \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ReviewRendererInterface::SHORT_VIEW;
    } else {
        $viewMode = 'list';
        $image = 'category_page_list';
        $showDescription = true;
        $templateType = \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ReviewRendererInterface::FULL_VIEW;
    }
    /**
     * Position for actions regarding image size changing in vde if needed
     */
    $pos = $block->getPositioned();
    ?>
    <div class="products wrapper <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $viewMode ?> products-<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $viewMode ?>">
        <?php $iterator = 1; ?>
        <ol class="products list items product-items">
            <?php /** @var $_product \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product */ ?>
            <?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
                <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ ($iterator++ == 1) ? '<li class="item product product-item">' : '</li><li class="item product product-item">' ?>
                <div class="product-item-info" data-container="product-grid">
                    <?php
                    $productImage = $block->getImage($_product, $image);
                    if ($pos != null) {
                        $position = ' style="left:' . $productImage->getWidth() . 'px;'
                            . 'top:' . $productImage->getHeight() . 'px;"';
                    }
                    ?>
                    <?php // Product Image ?>
                    <a href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" class="product photo product-item-photo" tabindex="-1">
                        <?= $productImage->toHtml() ?>
                    </a>
                    <div class="product details product-item-details">
                        <?php
                            $_productNameStripped = $block->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true);
                        ?>
                        <strong class="product name product-item-name">
                            <a class="product-item-link"
                               href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_product->getProductUrl() ?>">
                                <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?>
                            </a>
                        </strong>
                        <?= $block->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, $templateType) ?>
                        <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getProductPrice($_product) ?>
                        <?= $block->getProductDetailsHtml($_product) ?>

                        <div class="product-item-inner">
                            <div class="product actions product-item-actions"<?= strpos($pos, $viewMode . '-actions') ? $position : '' ?>>
                                <div class="actions-primary"<?= strpos($pos, $viewMode . '-primary') ? $position : '' ?>>
                                    <?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                                        <?php $postParams = $block->getAddToCartPostParams($_product); ?>
                                        <form data-role="tocart-form" data-product-sku="<?= $block->escapeHtml($_product->getSku()) ?>" action="<?= /* @NoEscape */ $postParams['action'] ?>" method="post">
                                            <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $postParams['data']['product'] ?>">
                                            <input type="hidden" name="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED ?>" value="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $postParams['data'][Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED] ?>">
                                            <?= $block->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
                                            <button type="submit"
                                                    title="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Cart')) ?>"
                                                    class="action tocart primary">
                                                <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Add to Cart') ?></span>
                                            </button>
                                        </form>
                                    <?php else: ?>
                                        <?php if ($_product->isAvailable()): ?>
                                            <div class="stock available"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('In stock') ?></span></div>
                                        <?php else: ?>
                                            <div class="stock unavailable"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Out of stock') ?></span></div>
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                </div>
                                <div data-role="add-to-links" class="actions-secondary"<?= strpos($pos, $viewMode . '-secondary') ? $position : '' ?>>
                                    <?php if ($addToBlock = $block->getChildBlock('addto')): ?>
                                        <?= $addToBlock->setProduct($_product)->getChildHtml() ?>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <?php if ($showDescription):?>
                                <div class="product description product-item-description">
                                    <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getShortDescription(), 'short_description') ?>
                                    <a href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_productNameStripped ?>"
                                       class="action more"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Learn More') ?></a>
                                </div>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?= ($iterator == count($_productCollection)+1) ? '</li>' : '' ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ol>
    </div>
    <?= $block->getToolbarHtml() ?>
    <?php if (!$block->isRedirectToCartEnabled()) : ?>
        <script type="text/x-magento-init">
        {
            "[data-role=tocart-form], .form.map.checkout": {
                "catalogAddToCart": {
                    "product_sku": "<?= /* @NoEscape */ $_product->getSku() ?>"
                }
            }
        }
        </script>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: please this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/245975/67660 it works for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a **catalog_category_view.xml** in your theme like below:

> app/design/frontend/Hiddentechies/bizkick/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml

and use the below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="category.product.addto.compare" remove="true" />
    </body>
</page>
```

Flush the cache and test.

Comment: how do we remove add to compare option from search result page. do you have any idea

Comment: Yes you can add the same code to you search result XML file.

Answer (score 0):

use this bock of code in your layout catalog default.xml file or catalog_category_view.xml file after  tag :

this will remove **add to compare** on product listing page.

```
<referenceBlock name="view.addto.compare" remove="true" />
```

this will remove **add to compare** from sidebar :

```
<referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.sidebar" remove="true" />
```

Comment: Its not working for me

Comment: you should add add this block of code in layout rather then in list.phtml, because this is appropriate way.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to disable or remove add to compare option from frontend side

you can do the following

go to app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

add below line just after  tag

```
<referenceBlock name="view.addto.compare" remove="true" />
```

run this command

> php bin/magento cache:clean && php bin/magento cache:flush

Comment: actually i am trying in list.phtml file not in theme

Comment: Do you want to disable for only product listing? or throughout the site?

Comment: yes i want to add only category product list page

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your module:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="sidebar.additional">
        <referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.sidebar" remove="true">
        </referenceBlock>
    </referenceContainer>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="your_module" template="Your_Module::template.phtml">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="section" xsi:type="string">homepage</argument>
                <argument name="position" xsi:type="number">0</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 2, you can actually now remove Compare products functionality via xml file. 
Compare products block is defined in `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout/default.xml`

and you can remove it by adding a `default.xml` file to your theme in: `<theme_dir>/Magento_Catalog/layout/default.xml`

inside which you remove your block as following:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.sidebar" remove="true"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

For the more information [magento.stackexchange.com/questions/96934](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/96934/magento-2-safe-and-easiest-way-to-disable-compare-products-wishlist-module/115278#115278) and also check another way [click here.](https://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/how-to-disableenable-magento-2-compare-product/)

Hope it helps!