# How to remove add to compare in catalog search result page?

Tags: magento2, catalogsearch

Actually I want to remove add to compare in catalog search result page

Comment: Hello, @hitesh if any of answer solves your concern then mark as accepted which will help future readers, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should add below code in your **Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml** file :

```
<referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.link" remove="true"/>
<referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.sidebar" remove="true"/>
```

This will delete from everywhere.

Comment: i want to remove in search result page for products in custom theme magento 2

Comment: if you add this piece of code in your theme's default.xml file it will remove from all places, however if you want to remove only from specific section then you should use this code in the required module / section layout.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add : 
`<referenceBlock name="catalogsearch.product.addto.compare" remove="true"/>`

into: 
`.../layout/catalogsearch_result_index.xml`

Answer (score 0):

I think the following links will help you in achiveing the same

https://bsscommerce.com/blog/how-to-disable-compare-in-magento-2-full-tutorial/
[Magento 2: Safe and easiest way to disable Compare products & Wishlist Module](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/96934/magento-2-safe-and-easiest-way-to-disable-compare-products-wishlist-module)

Comment: Please don't put single links, Describe about your solution

Answer (score 0):

**Disable compare in Layer Navigation:**

Compare products block is defined in

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout/default.xml

Now add a `default.xml` file to your theme in

> /Magento_Catalog/layout/default.xml

**Then remove your block as following:**

```
 <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd"> <body> <referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.sidebar" remove="true"/> </body> </page>
```

---

---

**Disable compare in Product Page and Category Page:**

- You add the following xml instruction to your theme’s default  xml
  file:

The xml file of your theme is located in

> /app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

**or**

> Magento_Catalog/layout/default.xml

**[Reference](https://bsscommerce.com/blog/how-to-disable-compare-in-magento-2-full-tutorial/)**

Answer (score 0):

if you want to disable or remove add to compare option from frontend side

you can do the following

go to app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

add below line just after body tag

```
<referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.sidebar" remove="true"/>
```

run this command

> php bin/magento cache:clean && php bin/magento cache:flush

it will remove from catalog product listing as well as from search result