# How do I hide images and compare button in category view List mode?

Tags: less-css, extend, category-view

Using Codazon Fastest theme, I have created `~/fastest/fastest_child/Magento_Catalog/web/css/source/_extend.less` which contains the following CSS extensions:

```
.catalog-category-view.product-item-photo {
  display: none
}
.action.tocompare.show-tooltip {
  display: none
}
```

I have also tried defining class more specifically, like this to remove it only from 'List' view:

```
.products-list.product-item-photo {
      display: none
}
```

Images and compare button are removed when I apply these styles from a Firefox style editor, but after compilation the website still displays them. Other styles in the same `_extend.less` are applying properly.

Is there something I am missing that would tell this style to override others, or is there somewhere else I should be creating .less?

Edit: I have run upgrade, deploy static content, and flushed cache. Other CSS changes from this same file are successful. These two specific classes are not applying.

I did try to remove the compare button via default.xml using [Magento 2: Safe and easiest way to disable Compare products & Wishlist Module](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/96934/112423) but this did not remove the compare buttons in category view.

Comment: after changing in less file, did you run all commands like deploy or upgrade etc ?

Comment: Yes. Updated question, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Find the image and compare button code: Within the template or file, search for the code that generates the image and compare button for each product in the category view. This code may involve HTML markup, CSS classes, and possibly JavaScript.

Hide the image: To hide the images, you can add CSS styles to hide the image elements. This can be achieved by adding a CSS class or inline style with the display: none; property. Locate the image code and apply the necessary CSS changes to hide the images.

Hide the compare button: Similarly, locate the code that generates the compare button and apply CSS styles to hide it. You can use the same approach as with the images, adding a CSS class or inline style to hide the compare button element.

Save and test: Save the changes to the template or file and preview the category view in List mode. Verify that the images and compare button are now hidden as intended.

Comment: This is what I have done already. My question contains the CSS you are describing.

Answer (score 0):

Go to terminal and run following command from magento root directry

```
rm -rf generated/*  var/cache/* var/page_cache/* var/view_preprocessed/*
php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento s:s:d -f
php bin/magento c:f
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Updated question, thank you. These steps were completed but these two classes are still not applying.